Can a translational torque cause a change in rotational angular momentum? gyroscope example
Please confirm if my understanding is correct: The example of a gyroscope suspended from a pivot is a case in which translational torque causes a change in the direction of rotational angular momentum:


the translational torque on the flywheel is $\tau_{trans} = \vec{d} \times M\vec{g}$
the rotational torque is 0
the translational angular momentum is non-zero when the flywheel precesses, but this is negligible for this example
the rotational angular momentum is $L_{rot} = I_{0}\omega$ and points along the axis of rotation; $I_{0}$ is the moment of inertia about the center of mass
$\dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{dt}\vec{L_{rot}}$ is perpendicular to $\vec{L_{rot}}$ and points in the direction of precession of the flywheel
since ${\tau = \dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{dt}}\vec{L}$, we must have that $\tau_{trans} = \dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{dt}\vec{L_{rot}} = I_{0}\alpha$ where $\alpha$ is angular acceleration; therefore the translational torque causes a rotational acceleration

Is this correct?

There is a 2012 answer by me specifically about onset of gyroscopic precession. The onset of gyroscopic precession involves nutation. The nutation usually decays very rapidly, due to friction, so generally the nutation is very transient. Regardless of the rate of decay of nutation: for onset of gyroscopic precession the nutation is essential. The expressions that you give do not cover the nutation aspect. In that sense the expressions that you give are incomplete. (Not necessarily incorrect, but incomplete.)
